# In Android Search View how to check if button is pressed

Tags: java, android

I want to know if a user pressed the search Icon from the SearchView not from the keyboard
I tried on Touch Listener,On Click listener and it doesn't work

[image]

```
    SearchView searchBar=(SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView1);
```

Comment: Are you referring the the button which starts the editing mode?

Comment: it has an image of a magnifying glass by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setOnSearchClickListener()` method to set an `OnClickListener` on the search button.

Comment: thank you I was using OnClickListener when it should setOnSearchClickListener()